# Filling values between 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code within a macro which auto fill the values between 2 cells on each row.  It just copies the same value across.

The code works perfectly well, but in some rows there is only 1 value and it copies right across to the end of the row.

I tried to add an If statement but I don't think I got the conditions right and it didn't work

```
Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Double
    Dim LastCol As Double
    Dim i As Double
    Dim j As Double
    Dim k As Double
    Dim RowVal As String

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
    LastRow = LastRow_1(wS)
    LastCol = LastCol_1(wS)

    For i = 7 To LastRow
        For j = 8 To LastCol
             With wS
                If .Cells(i, j) <> vbNullString Then
                    '1st value of the row found
                    RowVal = .Cells(i, j).Value
                    k = 1
                    'Fill until next value of that row

                    Do While j + k <= LastCol And .Cells(i, j + k) = vbNullString
                        .Cells(i, j + k).Value = RowVal
                        k = k + 1
                    Loop
                    'Go to next row
                    Exit For
                Else
                End If
            End With 'wS
        Next j
    Next i

Public Function LastCol_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
With wS
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastCol_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    Else
        LastCol_1 = 1
    End If
End With
End Function

Public Function LastRow_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
With wS
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow_1 = 1
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Expect it to do nothing if there is only one value in the row.

Comment: Can you please include the code for `LastCol_1()` and `LastRow_1()`?

Comment: Why not just add a check that there is more than one filled cell in the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to save the start and end columns in a couple of variables and have a separate loop to fill the values:

```
Sub Fill()

Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Double
    Dim LastCol As Double
    Dim i As Double
    Dim j As Double
    Dim k As Double
    Dim RowVal As String
    Dim startCol, endCol As Long


    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
    LastRow = LastRow_1(wS)
    LastCol = LastCol_1(wS)

    For i = 7 To LastRow
    startCol = 0
    endCol = 0
    With wS
        For j = 8 To LastCol

                If .Cells(i, j) <> vbNullString And startCol = 0 Then
                    'First non-empty cell found
                    RowVal = .Cells(i, j).Value
                    startCol = j
                Else
                    'Next non-empty cell found
                    If .Cells(i, j) <> vbNullString And startCol > 0 Then
                        endCol = j
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
        Next j

        ' Now fill values
        For j = startCol + 1 To endCol - 1
            .Cells(i, j).Value = RowVal
        Next j

    End With 'wS
    Next i
End Sub

'LastRow_1 and LastCol_1 as before.
```